# Can a character use multiple reactions in response to the same trigger?

Tags: opportunity-attack, reactions, pathfinder-2e

Let's say you're a fighter with [Combat Reflexes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=398), and [Boundless Reprisals](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=428). This means that on a given turn, you will have up to 3 reactions to use:  Two normal reactions, and one additional reaction which can only be used to take attacks of opportunity. If a creature provokes an attack of opportunity, can you use three attacks of opportunity against them at once?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No.**  CRB pg. 462, "Limitations on Triggers":

> You can use only one action in response to a given trigger.